Cannot run integration tests, app can't visit a route - Next JS, Playwright, Jenkins
I wanted to setup integration tests for our Next JS app (pages router). I was forced by company to use Jenkins and trying to run Playwright tests (checked Cypress as well - same results). One trick in this setup is parallel node server on fastify to handle mocks for SSR and server requests. Regardless of picked method I've got the same results. It looks like Next API server works fine, but still rest of the app isn't running properly (e.g. it can't visit page /login, but request to handler /api/healthcheck is OK). 
I tried many variants of those scripts to run this
"dev": "next dev",
"start:standalone": "HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1 node .next/standalone/server.js",
"mockserver:ci": "node ./tests/server/server.js",
"pw:e2e": "playwright test",
"pw:launch:ci": "start-test mockserver:ci http://localhost:8080 dev http://localhost:3000/api/healthcheck pw:e2e"

Using start-server-and-test lib to run fastify with next app and tests one by one.
I tried dev run and build run as well, with start:standalone command and copy-paste static assets in Jenkins:
stage('Copy next static files to standalone folder') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'cp -r .next/static .next/standalone/.next'
                        sh 'cp -r public .next/standalone'
                    }
                }

This is rest of Jenkins config for testing (rest is for linting and building - works fine):
 stage ('Playwright tests') {
            agent { docker { image 'mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.44.1-jammy' } }
            stages {
                stage('Bring back artifacts'){
                    steps {
                        unstash 'artifacts'
                        // unstash 'build' <- for attempts with builded version of app
                    }
                }
                stage('e2e-tests') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'npm run pw:launch:ci'
                    }
                }
            }
            post {
                always {
                    // junit checksName: 'Playwright integration tests', testResults: 'test-results/e2e-junit-results.xml'
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'test-results/**/*', fingerprint: true
                }
            }
        }

Sadly I wasn't able to find working solution. Everything is OK locally (with Cypress too). Here's the logfile for most common result, that I'm getting:
[2024-06-18T11:13:20.999Z] + npm run pw:launch:ci

[2024-06-18T11:13:20.999Z] 

[2024-06-18T11:13:20.999Z] > platform@0.3.15 pw:launch:ci

[2024-06-18T11:13:20.999Z] > start-test mockserver:ci http://localhost:8080 dev http-get://localhost:3000/login pw:e2e

[2024-06-18T11:13:20.999Z] 

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.254Z] 1: starting server using command "npm run mockserver:ci"

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.254Z] and when url "[ 'http://localhost:8080' ]" is responding with HTTP status code 200

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.254Z] 2: starting server using command "npm run dev"

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.254Z] and when url "[ 'http-get://localhost:3000/login' ]" is responding with HTTP status code 200

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.254Z] running tests using command "npm run pw:e2e"

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.254Z] 

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.254Z] 

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.254Z] > platform@0.3.15 mockserver:ci

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.254Z] > node ./tests/server/server.js

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.254Z] 

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] Available routes:

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] 

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] ╔═══════════╤═══════════════════════════════════════════════╗

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] ║ Method(s) │ Path                                          ║

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] ╟───────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────╢

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] ║       GET │ /                                             ║

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] ║      HEAD │ /                                             ║

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] ║      POST │ /v1/accounts/login                            ║

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] ║      HEAD │ /v1/me                                        ║

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] ║       GET │ /v1/me/                                       ║

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] ║      HEAD │ /v1/me/                                       ║

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] ║       GET │ /v1/me/memberships                            ║

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] ║      HEAD │ /v1/me/memberships                            ║

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] ║       GET │ /v1/organizations/:organizationId             ║

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] ║      HEAD │ /v1/organizations/:organizationId             ║

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] ║       GET │ /v1/organizations/:organizationId/memberships ║

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] ║      HEAD │ /v1/organizations/:organizationId/memberships ║

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] ╚═══════════╧═══════════════════════════════════════════════╝

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] 

[2024-06-18T11:13:21.511Z] {"level":30,"time":1718709201372,"pid":56,"hostname":"f4b3e917407a","msg":"Server listening at http://127.0.0.1:8080"}

[2024-06-18T11:13:23.409Z] {"level":30,"time":1718709203147,"pid":56,"hostname":"f4b3e917407a","reqId":"req-1","req":{"method":"HEAD","url":"/","hostname":"localhost:8080","remoteAddress":"127.0.0.1","remotePort":58942},"msg":"incoming request"}

[2024-06-18T11:13:23.409Z] {"level":30,"time":1718709203150,"pid":56,"hostname":"f4b3e917407a","reqId":"req-1","res":{"statusCode":200},"responseTime":2.529998779296875,"msg":"request completed"}

[2024-06-18T11:13:23.409Z] 

[2024-06-18T11:13:23.409Z] > platform@0.3.15 dev

[2024-06-18T11:13:23.409Z] > next dev

[2024-06-18T11:13:23.409Z] 

[2024-06-18T11:13:24.336Z] error This project's package.json defines "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.1". However the current global version of Yarn is 1.22.22.

[2024-06-18T11:13:24.336Z] 

[2024-06-18T11:13:24.336Z] Presence of the "packageManager" field indicates that the project is meant to be used with Corepack, a tool included by default with all official Node.js distributions starting from 16.9 and 14.19.

[2024-06-18T11:13:24.336Z] Corepack must currently be enabled by running corepack enable in your terminal. For more information, check out https://yarnpkg.com/corepack.

[2024-06-18T11:13:25.260Z]   ▲ Next.js 13.5.6

[2024-06-18T11:13:25.260Z]   - Local:        http://localhost:3000

[2024-06-18T11:13:25.260Z] 

[2024-06-18T11:13:25.260Z]  ✓ Ready in 1642ms

[2024-06-18T11:13:29.414Z]  ○ Compiling /login ...

[2024-06-18T11:13:29.669Z]  ✓ Compiled /login in 4.4s (1406 modules)

[2024-06-18T11:13:30.228Z]  ✓ Compiled in 426ms (1406 modules)

[2024-06-18T11:18:36.762Z] Error: Timed out waiting for: http-get://localhost:3000/login

[2024-06-18T11:18:36.762Z]     at /home/jenkins/workspace/orm_Build_Mocked-cypress-testing@2/node_modules/wait-on/lib/wait-on.js:131:31

[2024-06-18T11:18:36.762Z]     at doInnerSub (/home/jenkins/workspace/orm_Build_Mocked-cypress-testing@2/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/mergeInternals.js:22:31)

[2024-06-18T11:18:36.762Z]     at outerNext (/home/jenkins/workspace/orm_Build_Mocked-cypress-testing@2/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/mergeInternals.js:17:70)

[2024-06-18T11:18:36.762Z]     at OperatorSubscriber._this._next (/home/jenkins/workspace/orm_Build_Mocked-cypress-testing@2/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/OperatorSubscriber.js:33:21)

[2024-06-18T11:18:36.762Z]     at Subscriber.next (/home/jenkins/workspace/orm_Build_Mocked-cypress-testing@2/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:51:18)

[2024-06-18T11:18:36.762Z]     at AsyncAction.work (/home/jenkins/workspace/orm_Build_Mocked-cypress-testing@2/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/observable/timer.js:28:28)

[2024-06-18T11:18:36.762Z]     at AsyncAction._execute (/home/jenkins/workspace/orm_Build_Mocked-cypress-testing@2/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/scheduler/AsyncAction.js:79:18)

[2024-06-18T11:18:36.762Z]     at AsyncAction.execute (/home/jenkins/workspace/orm_Build_Mocked-cypress-testing@2/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/scheduler/AsyncAction.js:67:26)

[2024-06-18T11:18:36.762Z]     at AsyncScheduler.flush (/home/jenkins/workspace/orm_Build_Mocked-cypress-testing@2/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/scheduler/AsyncScheduler.js:38:33)

[2024-06-18T11:18:36.762Z]     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)

[2024-06-18T11:18:36.762Z]     at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)

[2024-06-18T11:18:36.762Z] 

script returned exit code 1

It's trying to visit /login page even when I'm trying to use /api/healthcheck as route to call for start-test command. No idea why it can return 200 for start-test command and be unavailable for playwright or cypress, while trying to visit.
